# Accessing an iframe from inside the iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

What I have is an iframe and the src is a document located on a different server.  I want to be able to adjust the size of the iframe dynamically.  However the CMS I'm using for work is rather limited and it will strip out a lot of my code to make adjustments, etc. so I'm having to try and rely on my code from the off site document.

What I want to do is use the offsite document to adjust the encapsulating iframe based on it's ID.  I've set the ID to the iframe, so I know everything that's being used, nothing is inside a blackbox for me.

Currently I'm this:

```
 var frame = $('#formFrame', window.parent.document);
 var height = $('#main').height();
 frame.height(height + 15);
 frame.width("700");
```

Where #formFram is the ID of the encapsulating iframe and #main is the encapsulating division on the offsite document.  First question is, can you actually do this?  Second question is, if you can actually do this then should the code I have work?  Because currently it's not working.

**This is all inside my $(document).ready() {} section of my jQuery src file.

Comment: Due to the Same-Origin Policy, that is impossible.

Comment: Well....damn that kind of sucks for me.  I guess I need to think of another way of handling it.